# Difference of similar type of pointers

Tags: c, pointers

Difference of two pointers of the same type is always one.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
int a = 5,b = 10,c;
int *p = &a,*q = &b;
c = p - q;
printf("%d" , c);
return 0;
}

Output is 1.
```

I dont get the reasoning behind it

Comment: This program exhibits undefined behavior.  You can only perform pointer arithmetic on two pointers if they both point to elements of the same array or to subobjects of the same class type.

Comment: Also, pointer arithmetic is done in units of the pointer type, not bytes.

Comment: So both pointing to int is not enough?

Comment: No. What do you expect the subtraction of those pointers to do ?

Comment: http://cquestionbank.blogspot.com/2008/02/c-pointer-questions-with-solutions.html  i was going through this tutorial and tried to execute the 13th question myself.. now probly it is junk

Comment: I thought the subtraction of pointers will give difference between 2 addresses. And the difference can vary.It can be 4 if they are allocated contigously.It can b 8,12 etc in multiples of 4. Is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: @Anusha Pachunuri Somewhat.  As others mention, you should not subtract pointers to different variables, as that yields undefined behavior.  Also, pointer aritmetic are done in the units of the pointer type, so 1 means "1 int", if you want bytes, you need 1*sizeof(int) (which might be 4). The variable might not be stored in memory, it might reside in a register, however your code taking the address of the variable could force it to reside in memory. And just because the C code declares the a variable first, doesn't mean it resides before b in memory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The behavior is undefined.

[C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.5.6 paragraph 9 says:

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the
>   same array object, or one past the last element of the array object;
>   the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array
>   elements.

Paragraph 7 in the same section says:

> For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is
>   not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the ﬁrst
>   element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its
>   element type.

Section 4 paragraph 2 says:

> If a "shall" or "shall not" requirement that appears outside of a 
>   constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined. Undefined behavior
>   is otherwise indicated in this International Standard by the words
>   "undefined behavior" or by the omission of any explicit definition  of
>   behavior. There is no difference in emphasis among these three; they
>   all describe "behavior that is undefined".

3.4.3 defines the term "undefined behavior" as:

> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or
>   of erroneous data, for which this International imposes no
>   requirements
>
> NOTE Possible undeﬁned behavior ranges from ignoring the situation
>   completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation
>   or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the
>   environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to
>   terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a
>   diagnostic message).

Given the declaration:

```
int a = 5, b = 10, c;
```

it's likely that evaluating `&b - &a` will yield a result that seems reasonable, such as `1` or `-1`.  (Reasonable results are always a possible symptom of undefined behavior; it's undefined, not required to crash.)  But the compiler is under no obligation to place `a` and `b` at any particular locations in memory relative to each other, and even if it does so, the subtraction is not guaranteed to be meaningful.  An optimizing compiler is free to transform your program in ways that *assume* that its behavior is well defined, resulting in code that can behave in arbitrarily bad ways if that assumption is violated.

By writing `&b - &a`, you are in effect promising the compiler that that's a meaningful operation.  As Henry Spencer famously said, "If you lie to the compiler, it will get is revenge."

Note that it's not just the result of the subtraction that's undefined, it's the *behavior* of the program that evaluates it.

---

Oh, did I mention that the behavior is undefined?

Comment: Yupp. Got it.Thanks for the detailed axplanation

Answer (score 5):

In fact, the behaviour of your program is undefined. The output *happens* to be `1` on your platform/compiler, but it could just as easily be something else.

Comment: Is it really undefined behavior (in the standard sense) or is the result itself undefined?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I am not sure I understand the distinction between the two possibilities.

Comment: Well by undefined behavior (from a standard perspective), I understand that *anything* can happen. Here, all that can happen is that you get different values depending on compiler or even run. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not trying to discredit your answer btw, I just thought that substracting two pointers is legal. Is it not? Is that part the UB? Is there a standard spec about this?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore:  The behavior is undefined.  You can only perform arithmetic using two pointers if both pointers point to elements of the same array or to subobjects of the same object (e.g., members of the same struct).

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I had already read your comment, but I've been looking in the standard and found nothing so far that is against this. Can you help out?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore:  For C++, see the long paragraph at C++11 §5.7/5, which ends with "otherwise, the behavior is undefined."  In C99, there is a similar paragraph where the additive and subtractive operators are specified.

Answer (score 4):

This code exhibits undefined behaviour because pointer arithmetic is only defined when the operands are both in the same array or struct.

The value of 1 comes about because the compiler has placed `a` and `b` next to each other in memory. Another compiler could do something different. Indeed the same compiler could do something different the next time you change the code.

Comment: Is it really undefined behavior (in the standard sense) or is the result itself undefined?

Comment: Well by undefined behavior (from a standard perspective), I understand that *anything* can happen. Here, all that can happen is that you get different values depending on compiler or even run. Am I wrong?

Comment: Which part of the program is undefined behavior? Is it UB to substract 2 pointers? Or what?

Comment: James' comment doesn't have a reference to the standard. I'm not saying it's not true.

Comment: Also, the standard doesn't specify what `rand()` returns, that doesn't mean it's undefined behavior :)

Comment: I don't know. I'm not trying to refute your answer, I just want some proof that it's valid. Like a spec from the standard.

Answer (score 0):

C compiler knows the size of each type. for example suppose `P` is a int pointer that refer to `address 0x0010`. if you add P by 1 (P++ or P=P+1), then the value of P is `0x0014`.

About your question, `a` and `b` variables declared tandems, in `physical memory` they tandems, and the head of each of them, has `4 bytes difference` with other. At this situation compiler knows the int size is 4 bytes. when you subtract 2 int pointer, the compiler `divide the result by 4`.

Comment: Whats with dividing the result by 4?

Comment: @anusha read nos's comment but this answer doesn't address the issue of undefined behaviour